# How one can find I am using virtual box Virtual Machine linux through Anydesk remote application?

Tags: privacy, virtualization, remote-desktop, network-access-control, virtualhost

I recently created a virtualbox virtual machine of Ubuntu 18.04 and installed Anydesk remote desktop app in it. An IT guy accessed my computers desktop via Anydesk app, but he is actually inside the Ubuntu Virtual Machine on Virtualbox. I don't even mentioned anything about Virtualbox, but after asking me my laptop model and brand, in less than one minute he asked me "Are you using Virtualbox VM?". I startled, he even mentioned which virtualization software I am using( virtual box) even there is VMWARE, Parallel, Nutanix and manymore. My host machine is Linux Mint. Can anyone explain how our IT guy managed to know that I am running Ubuntu 18.04 inside virtualbox as a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Can you elaborate how he find I am using virtual box using ifconfig.

Comment: Does this question help? [Easy way to determine virtualization technology](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89714/easy-way-to-determine-virtualization-technology)

Comment: Sounds like a lucky guess/assumption? If he knew, why would he have to ask?

Answer (score 1):

One way to determine that is

> **ifconfig**

The default Mac addresses map to the VM vendors.

Comment: I told him my wifi and bluetooth devices arenot detecting in my OS(virtualbox), is there any chance he can guess I am using Virtual Machine, since driver problem for wifi adapter is inherent in Virtual box. But I don't understand how he pinpointed my virtualization software. I know VM ware and Virtual box are two common tool, but he several time thoroughly asked me is it virtualbox.

Comment: If you allowed him remote access, then you have a network card (virtual). The mac address will be a VM product code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Actually it's the username. When we create a virtual os in virtual box the default name will be -virtualBox, in my case Ubuntu-virtualBox. When we open a terminal this name is vividly displayed in the shell prompt. That's why he found out I am using virtual Box, even without running any other command in front of me. I know from Jim Browining videos we can actually change all details of the virtual box hardware and fake it. But This is not that case, since he doesn't even disconnect or put my screen blackout during the entire operation. 
So guy watchout for virtual box virtual machine name.